# Why does flagging as "too broad" also count as "duplicate"?

Tags: discussion, bug, flagging

I flagged a question as "too broad". Then I realized the author had previously posted the same question and decided to change my flag to "duplicate". I retracted the "broad" flag, but the user interface now won't let me flag as "duplicate" because it seems to think I already flagged as "duplicate" and then retracted it.

Why does flagging as "too broad" also count as flagging "duplicate"? Is this a bug? (I have tagged as 'bug' but am obviously uncertain)

Comment: That does sound buggy.

Comment: It doesn't, but I believe if you retract a post flag, you cannot flag the post again, thus explaining the behavior you see. Someone else might be able to confirm. (I have no convenient outstanding flag or vote to check.)

Comment: @MichaelKjörling That's not the behavior I saw. It would let me pick any of the other flags, just not "duplicate" or "should be closed".

Comment: Ah, fair enough. You might want to make that explicit in the question. That does indeed sound wrong.

Comment: I just tested on this question. I closed as too broad. Then I retracted. Then I tried closing again. I couldn't pick any of the options.

Comment: @SRM Then maybe the bug was that it didn't grey out all of the options it should have?   Also, so this means we're not allowed to change our flag? What if we made a mistake?